# How to properly forward parameters from a POST result and avoid refresh (re-submit), with Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, post, submit

This is a basic issue, when submitting and performing a post, you normally want to avoid giving the user the chance to re-iterate the submit by refreshing or going back and forth with browser history.

(Backend re-submit, controls and checking is not questioned here. Of course they should be in place for security)

My solution was to have in Laravel web routes defined a post and a get route.

Like:

```
 Route::post('/action',  'ActionController@doAction')->name('do.action');
 Route::get('/action',   'ActionController@doActionConfirm')->name('do.action.confirm');
```

In ActionController something like:

```
public function doAction(Request $request)
{
 ....

  return redirect()->route('do.action.confirm', [ 'data' =>
        base64_encode(json_encode([
        'action_id'=> $action_id,
        'sent_to'=> $email,
        'sent_success'=> $sent_success,
        'sent_errors'=> $sent_errors,

    ]))]);

}


 ....

public function doActionConfirm(Request $request)
{
   return view('confirmation')->with('data',$request->input('data'));
}
```

Then in my confirmation.blade.php get that $data decoded and displayed.

---

Is this the correct way to do it with Laravel?

What I don't like here:
is there's a better and more elegant way to forward data from the redirect()

is there a better way to manage get parameters to the GET route just to avoid people understanding and trying to inject unwanted data to the confirmation blade? (even if they will obtain nothing but no-sense views..because the page is doing nothing, it's simply displaying data in HTML blade)